# working node.js projects on windows 10 now no longer working

Tags: node.js, npm

Node.js projects are no longer working.  Have node.js 7.10.x npm 4.2.1

Projects that were working are no longer working.  I uninstalled node.js, removed npm-cache, reinstalled fresh.  Deleted node_modules directory, ran npm install on project's package.json and npm start xxxx etc. No matter what project I run, the error remains the same as shown below. The same projects installed on Linux Ubuntu work just fine.

No clue as to why these projects are no longer working.  The following error is consistent with each node project I've tested.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "test"
npm ERR! node v7.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! muber@1.0.0 test: `NODE_ENV=test nodemon --exec 'mocha --recursive -R min'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the muber@1.0.0 test script 'NODE_ENV=test nodemon --exec 'mocha --recursive -R min''.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
```

Comment: remove node.js of version 7.10.x and install 7.0.0. Hope, that it`ll helps .

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem is if it works on Linux but not the Windows machine. Windows cannot run CLI scripts the same; it requires a different syntax.

To fix it, you simply have to do `npm install --save cross-env` and then in your `package.json` file, add `cross-env` to the beginning of the script declaration:

ie:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "NODE_ENV=test nodemon --exec 'mocha --recursive -R min'"
},
```

will become:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nodemon --exec 'mocha --recursive -R min'"
},
```

That should fix it.

To fix it on Windows, you'd have to change it to (I think):

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "NODE_ENV=test&&nodemon --exec 'mocha --recursive -R min'"
},
```

You can do a quick test and change it to that and run it. If that fixes it, this is exactly your problem. But, that will break it on Linux, so generally, `cross-env` is recommended. Make sure you dont have spaces also at `&&`.

Comment: Thank you for that reply.  I'll definitely give it a try...head swimming keeping up with this stuff.

Comment: That didn't do it.  I even simplified the start script.  Same problem.  Apparently recent changes to node.js WRT to running on windows just got more complicated...

Comment: Can you update to newest node and npm? Newest is node 8.6 and npm 5.4.2. Node has some performance gains around 8.0. Something about the v8 runtime optimizer. I don't remember any like invasive breaking changes since your versions. If you want, install node over top of yours, from nodejs.org and do `npm install -g npm` to update npm.

Comment: That version of node is fine though. It has all the good stuff. NPM should probably be updated though. If I understand correctly, its on par with Yarn now.